How to call SHA3 API's using Openssl Assembly?
I am trying to develop SHA3 support using the assembly support available in below link: https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/crypto/sha/asm/keccak1600p8-ppc.pl
Am able to generate .s file from the above perl file and compile/link the same in my project. Now, I need to write a source file that would 'functions' from the assembly file.
Came across the below SHA3 generic function that I assume works for all SHA3 family functions(including SHAKE). https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/crypto/sha/keccak1600.c#L1153
My question if I use the 'SHA3_sponge' function from above and it uses 'SHA3_absorb' and 'SHA3_squeeze' that are available in the assembly file, will it be sufficient ?
Reference : https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Cryptogams_SHA
